# Video tag cannot load from cache in iOS Safari in NextJS mweb

Tags: reactjs, caching, safari, html5-video, next.js13

I'm using a service worker to store video blob in cache in iOS Safari. Since Safari doesn't directly cache video data using this SW ([here](https://bug-232076-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=442151)).

This solution works well with the **React** version of my project but it doesn't work when I use the same in **NextJS** App

Any idea on why this is happening and is there any workaround?

I've checked for all the possible reasons this SW may not work but am not able to debug this. Is there any reason why video tags don't load from cache on NextJS?

I'm temporarily storing the blobs in a video array and loading it from there as a hacky cache fix but this isn't ideal.